# How to configure CAPTCHA in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7

I have a small Drupal site up and running.. hfne.consius.se

To avoid spambots I have installed CAPTCHA. In the configuration I enabled it on the "Create new account" tab.

Despite this there are some spambots registring new users every 2 minute.

I guess I am doing something wrong her. Can anyone give me a tip what to do to prevent this unwanted registrations.

//regards

//lg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CAPTCHA](https://drupal.org/project/captcha) module. To add captcha in in drupal registration form there is no need to edit any single line of code. First you download and install the module then go to module settings page (**admin/config/people/captcha**) and enable the captcha for user registration form.

Comment: Yes,, I know. I have also learned that only using CAPTCHA is not enough. I have added other security modules also htt:BL and Spamicide. Togheter they seems the number of spams to almost 0. Only gets something like 5 spams every 24 hours. Maby there are a way to tune this more.